# How does Tx Power affect the Free Space Path Loss model?

Tags: energy, propagator, radio-frequency, radio, radiometry

On this [website](https://www.everythingrf.com/rf-calculators/free-space-path-loss-calculator) one can use the FSPL model to calculate the Path Loss. This is typically interpreted online as the theoretical signal strength (in dB) that one may receive (e.g. from some WiFi). However, assuming that the G(TX) does not contain the information of the actual transmission power (but in fact some -+delta), how does the transmission power itself affect the FSPL? Or is the FSPL independent from that?

Comment: I do not know what happens in a black hole but here on earth the path loss is independent of the transmitted power, and this is true at any frequency.

Comment: A typical WiFi radio adapter that one can find on a PC or a Smartphone, expresses the signal strength (e.g. from a router broadcasting at 2.4GHz) in dBs. And most online posts I find suggest that this can be calculated in theory by the FSPL. However, in practice, if one can increase the Transmition power of the router, the DBs will increase at the receiver. Therefore, I guess that these are indeed dependent on TX Power. If that is true, then how can the FSPL which is independent from the TX Power, explain the Received Signal strength on the PC?

Comment: Doubling transmit power will double received power but their ratio is independent of the path loss that is in fact the ratio itself expressed usually in a logarithmic scale as in dB-s..

Comment: As an example, this Android App https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phuongpn.wifisignalstrengthmeter measures the signal strength in dBs (e.g. -61dBm). Is this comparable with what the FSPL model describes?

Comment: I'm correcting myself and I mention that the devices return 'dBm' units which are decibel-based unit of power referenced to 1 mW.

Comment: Friis's formula is $\frac{P_r}{P_t}= G_tG_r (\frac{d}{4\pi\lambda})^2$ where in dB's $FPLS=10log(\frac{d}{4\pi\lambda})^2$. To calculate the received power when $P_t$ is given you also need the antenna gains $G_r, G_t$

Comment: ...above should have written $(\frac{\lambda}{4\pi d})^2$